# Error while running Munit test flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, munit

I am getting below error while just running MUnit Project I just started learning MUnit:

> **Could not find or load main class org.mule.munit.runner.remote.MunitRemoteRunner**

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because you have Maven enabled for your project. Simply right click on your project and select MUnit--> Configure MUnit Support. Alternatively add Mnuit dependency to your pom.xml

......
    1.1.0
    3.6.1

.......
    
        com.mulesoft.munit.tools
        munit-maven-plugin
        ${munit.version}
        
            
                test
                test
                
                    test
                
            
        
        
            
                true
                
                    html
                
            
        
    


...
    
            com.mulesoft.munit
            mule-munit-support
            ${mule.munit.support.version}
            test
        
    
            com.mulesoft.munit
            munit-runner
            ${munit.version}
            test